# Critical points of analytic function (exercise from Gamelin)

Tags: complex-analysis

The following is an exercise from Gamelin VIII.5.4

> Suppose that $f(z)$ is analytic at $z_0$. Show that if the set of $z$ such that $\text{Re } f(z) = \text{Re } f(z_0)$ consists of just one curve passing through $z_0$, then $f'(z_0) \ne 0$. Show also that if the set of $z$ such that $|f(z)| = |f(z_0)|$ consists of just one curve passing through $z_0$, then $f'(z_0) \ne 0$.

I would like to apply the following Theorem:

> let $f(z)$ be analytic at $z_0$. Suppose $z_0$ is a critical point of order $m-1$ for $f(z)$ with critical value $f(z_0) = w_0$. Let $\rho > 0$ satisfy $f(z) \ne w_0$ for $0 < |z-z_0| \le \rho$ and $\delta > 0$ satisfy $|f(z) - w_0| \ge \delta$ for $|z - z_0| = \rho$. Then for each $w$ such that $0 < |w - w_0| < \delta$, the equation $f(z) = w$ has exactly $m$ distinct solutions $z_1 (w) , \dots, z_m(w)$ in the disk of radius $\rho$ centered at $z_0$, which can be chosen to be analytic on a slit disk.

1. Suppose $z_0$ is a critical point of order $m-1$. I wish to show $m = 1$. The theorem says that for each value $w \ne f(z_0)$ in a neighborhood of $f(z_0)$, there are $m$ solutions to $f(z) = w$, where $z\ne z_0$ is in a neighborhood of $z_0$. 
   I want to say at this point that taking the points $z$ closer to $z_0$, these will correspond to $m$ curves passing through $z_0$ and so by assumption, $m = 1$. Is this the right approach?
2. I am hesitant on the above approach since nowhere did I use the fact about it being true for real part only. So it seems, if the above works, then this follows by almost the exact same argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D$ be a small disk centered at $z_0$ which does not contain any zeros of $f(z)-f(z_0)$ other than $z_0$ and $C=\partial D$. The curve $
\operatorname{Re}\, f(z)=\operatorname{Re}\, f(z_0)$, say $l$, divides $D$ into just two parts $D^+$ and $D^-$ by the assumption.
We may assume that $\operatorname{Re}\, f(z)>\operatorname{Re}\, f(z_0)$ in $D^+$ and $\operatorname{Re}\, f(z)<\operatorname{Re}\, f(z_0)$ in $D^-$. 
Also $l$ divides $C$ into $C^+$ and $C^-$. 
We note that the image $f(C^+)$ of $C^+$ lies in the half-plane 
$\operatorname{Re}\,w>\operatorname{Re}\, w_0$ and $f(C^-)$ lies in $\operatorname{Re}\,w<\operatorname{Re}\, w_0$. See illustration in Fig.1 below.
[image]

Thus $f(C)$ can go around $w_0$ only once, and hence 
$$ \int_{C} d\arg (f(z)-f(z_0))=2\pi.$$

If we suppose that $
f(z)-f(z_0)=(z-z_0)^n\cdot \varphi (z)$ 
with $\varphi (z)\ne 0 $ in a neighborhood of $z_0$, then  $$ \int_{C} d\arg (f(z)-f(z_0))=2n\pi.$$
Hence we have $n=1$ which implies $f^\prime(z_0)\ne 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful explanation and illustration! I have only one question: why may we assume that the difference of the real parts is positive on one side and negative on the other side?

Comment: Suppose that, for instance, $u=\operatorname{Re}f(z)-\operatorname{Re}f(z_0)>0$ on both sides. Then $u\ge 0$ on $D$ and $u=0$ on $l$. The maximum principle for harmonic functions yields that $u$ is a constant. Therefore $u$ is positive on one side and negative on the other side.